# Casting during assignment in Java

Tags: java, casting

Is there a use in casting during variable assignment in Java?

For example, I have two classes, Person and Student that inherits from person:

- Person| -id: int
- Student -> Person | -gpa: double

Then in the main I have the following code:

```
Student S = new Student(1, 4.00);
Person P = (Student)S;
System.out.println(P.getId() + " " + ((Student)P).getGpa());
```

IntelliJ tells me that the casting in `P = (Student)S` is redundant, and it works if I just cast when calling the getGpa method:

```
Student S = new Student(1, 4.00);
Person P = S;
System.out.println(P.getId() + " " + ((Student)P).getGpa());
```

However, it gives me an error if I cast during assignment but not again when I call getGpa:

```
Student S = new Student(1, 4.00);
Person P = (Student)S;
System.out.println(P.getId() + " " + P.getGpa());
```

So my question is - is there a case when casting during assignment is useful? Or is it allowed but always redundant because you still have to tell the compiler with every method call that you are casting to a subtype?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is your question about casting in general during an assignment or only about casting something to the type that it already is. If the question is "is it always redundant to cast something to the type it already is", the answer is yes. `S` is of type `Student`, so casting it to `Student` does nothing. `P` is of type `Parent`, so casting it to `Student` does something.

Comment: It's redundant because a Student *is-a* Person so no cast is required. One case for casting on assignment is `something = (Something) foo();`. Where `foo` returns an Object.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am asking about casting between objects rather than primitives - so I thought that you would only allowed to upcast/downcast based on an inheritance relationship. In this case I am not casting to the same type, I am down casting to Student such that I can access the getGpa method in Student. So there's a point, but I'm asking specifically why even allow someone to do `P = (Student)S` if I just have to cast it again when I call the getGpa method anyway.

Comment: "Or is it allowed but always redundant because you still have to tell the compiler with every method call that you are casting to a subtype?" - how is casting an expression to a *subtype* (this is called a 'downcast') redundant? (A type is not a subtype of itself, and casting an expression to the same type is .. erm .. silly.)

Comment: I don't mean redundant to do downcasting in general. I mean that you _must_ downcast when calling a method, such as in `((Student)P).getGpa()`. Therefore, is there anything accomplished by _also_ downcasting during assignment such as `P = (Student)S;`? If you always have to downcast when calling a method, seems like it's pointless and confusing to also do it during the assignment (see the answer below from @dasblinkenlight)

Comment: Oh - OK, I think I was confusing up and down casting. So the (Student)S does nothing, and during the assignment to P, there is an implicit upcast. On the other hand, when I want to downcast, you can in fact downcast during assignment and then call methods without redundancy. Thank you @DavidSchwartz and @user2864740!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying in this comment, but I think I follow what you are saying in your other comments :) and I would happily choose your other comments as the answer, but I don't see a way to "accept" a comment as an answer.

Comment: You can't. I'm not looking for you to accept anything I said as an answer tho. The accepted answer answers your questions, I was hoping you would acknowledge some of the content of that answer as well as comment(s) is not great which I think I've pointed out in other comments. Most of what I said deals with "How do I avoid casting and instanceof checks" which would probably be more informative and useful considering the example code you've given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting during assignment is not redundant when you know something the compiler doesn't.

When you assign `Student` object to `Person` variable, there is no need to cast because the compiler knows `Student` inherits from `Person`. But if you assign `Person` object to `Student` variable, the compiler doesn't know if the `Person` object is also `Student` object.

In that case you'd have to use cast during assignment to tell the compiler you know this specific `Person` object is also `Student`. You would usually verify this first with `instanceof`.

```
if (P instanceof Student) {
  Student S2 = (Student) P; // here the casting during assignment is required
  S2.getGpa();
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, but I have a question for how it is in practice. It seems like the only reason P would be an instance of Student is if you actually assigned a Student object to a Person variable. It seems more appropriate to just assign something to the same type it is, and cast when  you use it differently...why do something like `Person P = new Student();`?

Comment: You might have a list of `Person` objects that you want to iterate and perform certain actions only on certain types of objects. You may also have a function that accepts a `Person` object but needs to do something special in case it's also `Student`.

Comment: @allstar, "why do something like Person P = new Student();?" Because you love OOP and the benefits of polymorphism.

Comment: This is why you would use instanceof. But wouldn't you still have to doing the casting when actually calling a method to do the something special?

Comment: Yes, after running `instanceof` and realizing it's a type that needs special treatment, you would need to cast. That's were assignment casting will help you. A better real world example of this would be with interfaces. You may have a method that accepts `Person` and then checks and casts to specific interfaces that have more capabilities.

Comment: @allstar, I would think if you find yourself using `instanceof` often then there's probably a better way. I would treat people as people and students as students. Don't make a method that does something to all people and then something special to those that are students (bad).If something has to be done to students but not all people write *another* method and pass it students. If you have many different types of people, perhaps map them to lists. When you work on people you use the whole map, when you want students do `list = map.get(studentKey);`

Comment: @kichik aye that's also a good use case. My question is less about purpose of casting, more about the language. It seems like casting _before_ you actually call any methods is redundant, as you must cast when calling the actual methods.

Comment: Are you talking about the difference between `((Student) P).getGpa()` and `Student S = (Student) P; S.getGpa()`? You can cast at either point. If you are going to call multiple methods of `Student`, it might be nicer looking to cast once.

Comment: I think I was confusing up and down casting. So the (Student)S does nothing, and during the assignment to P, there is an implicit upcast. On the other hand, when I want to downcast, you can in fact downcast during assignment once and then call methods without redundancy. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> IntelliJ tells me that the casting in `P = (Student)S` is redundant

That is absolutely correct. `Person` is the base class of `Student`, so any `Student` is automatically a `Person`.

> So my question is - is there a case when casting during assignment is useful?

No, it is redundant and it reduces readability of your code.

Casting to base class remains useless even when you must treat derived objects in a uniform way, such as storing them in a collection of objects of the base type, e.g.

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
...
Student student = new Student();
...
list.add((Person)student); // <<= This is redundant, too. Don't do it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting is useful and often necessary when you know for sure that your object of a class A is, in fact, an object of a subclass B and you can not express that knowledge in the program in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `P = (Student)S` there is no benefit to doing this if S is an instance of `Student` as the compiler already knows this.

If you subsequently had `Student Q = P` however this wouldn't work and you would instead need to write `Student Q = (Student)P`.  The reason why the cast is required is that there is no guarantee that P is actually a student (for example it could be a tutor, which is also a person).